# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'vin')

Tags: javascript

For some reason I have variables outside of my function and I'm updating that variable in my function but when I call that variable in another function I get a undefined typeError

```
let bikeShare = []
let stations = []

function startRide(vin) {
  bikeShare = bikeShare.map((bike) => {
    bike.vin === vin ? { ...bike, checkOut: true } : bike 
  })
  return {}
}

function endRide(vin) {
  console.log(bikeShare)
  bikeShare = bikeShare.map((bike) => {
    bike.vin === vin && bike.checkOut 
      ? { ...bike, checkOut: false, totalRides: bike.totalRides + 1  } 
      : bike 
  })
  return {}
}

function createBike(color = 'red') {
  const vin = bikeShare.length + Date.now();
  const payload = { vin, color, checkOut: false, totalRides: 0 }

  bikeShare.push(payload);

  return payload
}

const bike_1 = createBike('red')
const bike_2 = createBike('blue')
const bike_7 = createBike('green')

startRide(bike_1.vin) // in the startRide function I get an array [undefined, undefined, undefined] 
endRide(bike_1.vin)
```

Comment: The body of the `map` argument function in `startRide` is enclosed in curly braces. Remove the braces or put `return bike` inside the braces to stop it returning `undefined`.

Comment: Don't use `map` instead of `forEach`

Answer (score 1):

You are in the `startRide()` function not returning the result of each assignment in the `.map` method, so it returns `undefined` which why you see the array of undefined values.

This should fix it:

```js
let bikeShare = []
let stations = []

function startRide(vin) {
  bikeShare = bikeShare.map((bike) => {
    return bike.vin === vin ? { ...bike, checkOut: true } : bike 
  })
  return {}
}

function endRide(vin) {
  console.log(bikeShare)
  bikeShare = bikeShare.map((bike) => {
    bike.vin === vin && bike.checkOut 
      ? { ...bike, checkOut: false, totalRides: bike.totalRides + 1  } 
      : bike 
  })
  return {}
}

function createBike(color = 'red') {
  const vin = bikeShare.length + Date.now();
  const payload = { vin, color, checkOut: false, totalRides: 0 }

  bikeShare.push(payload);

  return payload
}

const bike_1 = createBike('red')
const bike_2 = createBike('blue');
const bike_7 = createBike('green');

startRide(bike_1.vin) // in the startRide function I get an array [undefined, undefined, undefined] 
endRide(bike_1.vin)
```

Answer (score 0):

To lift this out of comment, the body of the `map` argument function in `startRide` is enclosed in curly braces. You could remove the braces or put `return bike` inside the braces to stop it returning `undefined`.

However, setting `bike.vin` to a bike "payload" object with `checkout` set to `true`, leaving `bike.checkout` set to `false`, is a bug. One solution might be to use  `find` instead of `map`:

```js
let bikeShare = []
let stations = []

function startRide(vin, start = true) {
  const bike = bikeShare.find(bike=>bike.vin === vin);
  if( bike) {
    bike.checkOut = start;
  }
  return bike; // for debugging
}

function endRide(vin) {
  return startRide( vin, false);
}

function createBike(color = 'red') {
  const vin = bikeShare.length + Date.now();
  const payload = { vin, color, checkOut: false, totalRides: 0 }
  bikeShare.push(payload);
  return payload
}

const bike_1 = createBike('red')
const bike_2 = createBike('blue')
const bike_7 = createBike('green')

console.log( startRide(bike_1.vin));
console.log( endRide(bike_1.vin));
```